# ReSharper's SourceTemplate (postfix templates) doesn't work with Xamarin PCL projects - how to make it work?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, resharper, portable-class-library

ReSharper's [Source Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Source_Templates.html) (aka postfix templates) don't seem to work with Xamarin PCL projects.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: How exactly they do not work? Do you have a source template defined in the referenced project and can't see it in the completion?

Comment: @SlavaTutushkin, exactly. I have `SourceTemplate` defined, and don't have them in the completion list. The thing is that in another project (same solution) it works - only in the PCL libraries they are missing from the completion list. Do you have a PCL project in which they appear?